# Firebase functions - Not able to deploy python functions into project

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to deploy some python functions into an existing Firebase project through the CLI.

The project already has some Javascript functions, and when I try to connect the Python codebase through the CLI, I can get as far as - firebase init functions, but I am only presented with 2 options for selecting the development language (Javascript/Typescript, but not Python)

[image]

Firebase CLI looks to be globally updated to the latest

I've been trying to follow the instructions here to try to set this up https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd#python-preview_2

installed from npm list -g:

firebase-tools@12.5.2

firebase@10.3.0

Comment: What are you observing when you say "Firebase CLI looks to be globally updated to the latest"?  If you run `firebase --version` you will know for sure which version you're running in your shell, and you can compare that to what you see on npm.  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: Installed version for firebase is 10.2.2

Comment: OK, so your PATH is including a different (much older) version than what you say you have installed with npm.